# Django exception causing hung process with uwsgi & S3 key check

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

We are running a django app using uwsgi that hangs when it checks for a file on S3 that isn't there.  We receive an exception email, suggesting it has been thrown, but the process remains stuck on the key.exists function.  We're baffled as to why it's not exiting, and these calls are causing our system to, eventually, completely choke up.  Any help is appreciated!

```
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py lineno = 414 function = exists line = return k.exists()
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py lineno = 539 function = exists line = return bool(self.bucket.lookup(self.name, headers=headers))
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py lineno = 142 function = lookup line = return self.get_key(key_name, headers=headers)
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py lineno = 192 function = get_key line = key, resp = self._get_key_internal(key_name, headers, query_args_l)
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py lineno = 199 function = _get_key_internal line = query_args=query_args)
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py lineno = 664 function = make_request line = retry_handler=retry_handler
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py lineno = 1070 function = make_request line = retry_handler=retry_handler)
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py lineno = 943 function = _mexe line = response = connection.getresponse()
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py lineno = 1045 function = getresponse line = response.begin()
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py lineno = 409 function = begin line = version, status, reason = self._read_status()
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py lineno = 365 function = _read_status line = line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py lineno = 476 function = readline line = data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py lineno = 305 function = recv line = return self.read(buflen)
thread_id = uWSGIWorker10Core0 filename = /usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py lineno = 224 function = read line = return self._sslobj.read(len)
```

- python: 2.7.5+
- Django: 1.6.10 (I know... we're upgrading during our next release cycle)
- uwsgi: 2.0.11.1
- boto: 2.36.0
- django-storages: 1.1.8

Comment: Really seems rather weird that you get an exception mail, while the thread is stuck. How do you know it's still stuck in the `exists` function, after the mail gets sent? In case you don't know those, [pytracebacker-sockets](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Tracebacker.html) may help with analyzing, [harakiri](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Glossary.html#term-harakiri) with recovery.

Comment: I don't know for certain that's what's happening, it's entirely possible that the exception was sent by a different worker, and this one is just stuck on the exists.  The traceback was from pytracebacker-sockets, but I don't want to add harakiri until I have a good idea what's happening!

Comment: Well, *this* thread is stuck while already reading from the network. So, there should be a timeout. Besides making sure that S3 access is fast from exactly where the Django process is running, I'd watch that particular worker using IPDB or with logging, let it timeout, and see what it does afterwards. Maybe the requests are just slow enough to fill up all your uWSGI workers? Also, it'd be good to know if the exception mail is reproducibly connected to the waiting.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll keep investigating.